# Java Different MD5 output for same input?

Tags: java, cryptography, md5

My code to generate md5 looks like

```
@Nonnull
static String getAuthCode(@Nonnull final String email, @Nonnull final String memberExternalId,
                          @Nonnull final String clientId, @Nonnull final String clientSecret) {
    final MessageDigest messageDigest = getMessageDigest("MD5");
    final String stringForHashCode = email + ":" + memberExternalId + ":" + clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
    messageDigest.update(stringForHashCode.getBytes());
    return new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString();
}
```

I run the test as

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(getAuthCode("a", "b", "c", "d"));
}
```

and I get the output as

```
306937959255909402080036399104389354327
```

When I run the same test on online [website](http://www.md5.cz/), I get the output as

```
e6ea19c62a3763c7b78c475652c51357
```

for same input `a:b:c:d`

**Question**

- Why are they different?
- How can I get the output similar to what I get online? which is `e6ea19c62a3763c7b78c475652c51357`?

Comment: `messageDigest.update(stringForHashCode.getBytes());` <-- this will use the default JVM encoding. Is that what  you want? Rule of thumb: _always_ specify the encoding!

Comment: Not sure what encoding will give me result similar to what I get online

Comment: I even tried `messageDigest.update(stringForHashCode.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));` but the result is still the same

Answer (score 3):

The problem pointed out in comments *is* a problem - you should define which encoding you want to use. I'd recommend using UTF-8, e.g.

```
messageDigest.update(stringForHashCode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

A *bigger* problem, however, is that you're printing out a `BigInteger` created from the digest - which is printing it out in decimal. The result you're getting from the online tool is in *hexadecimal* instead.

While you could convert the `BigInteger` into hex, I would personally avoid creating a `BigInteger` in the first place - you'd need to work out padding etc. Instead, just use one of the *many* libraries available for converting a `byte[]` to hex, e.g. [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) with its [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class.

Comment: Guava's `Hashing.md5().hashString(str, UTF_8).toString()` also prints out hex.